# Smash products of pointed spaces is really not associative

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

The canonical bijective map $\mathbb{N} \wedge (\mathbb{Q} \wedge \mathbb{Q}) \to (\mathbb{N} \wedge \mathbb{Q}) \wedge \mathbb{Q}$ is not an isomorphism of pointed spaces (i.e. homeomorphism), see [SE/270469](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270469).

How can we prove that there is no isomorphism between $\mathbb{N} \wedge (\mathbb{Q} \wedge \mathbb{Q})$ and $(\mathbb{N} \wedge \mathbb{Q}) \wedge \mathbb{Q}$ at all?

Comment: Do you mean "pointed isomorphism" or "isomorphism" ?

Comment: Isomorphism := isomorphism in the category we work in. No need to add "pointed" here since we talk about pointed spaces. (Similarly, "linear isomorphism" is redundant when talking about vector spaces, etc.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I actually meant homeomorphism when I wrote isomorphism. Though I suspect every homeomorphism must be pointed in this case.

Comment: As far as I can see both products have only one point where they are not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The question will be continued at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196084 and therefore may be closed here.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Would you mind answering this question based on the MO thread so that it doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered by Eric Wofsey at mathoverflow.

[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196084)